# How to setup cgi for php5-apache

Tags: php, perl, docker, cgi, fastcgi

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM php:5-apache

RUN docker-php-source extract \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysql mysqli pdo pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-source delete
```

Unfortunately, when I click on a cgi file I see the actual cgi script rather than the HTML file inside the browser:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
...
```

How is it possible to configure cgi?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Why are you installing all those PHP modules and tagging this question [tag:php] when the CGI program is written in Perl?

Comment: Don't use `-w`! Use `use warnings;`! And always `use strict;`!

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:fastcgi] when you are using CGI? (For that matter, why aren't you using FastCGI?)